# How to combine Android/Java Library with Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a android TV app and recently I tried it on my new Oculus Quest. It's pretty cool but I want it to have 3D interface when running on VR devices. However, I have some essential java library that I don't know how to migrate. Is there a way to combing Unity UI with android codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a pretty good Tutorial here:

http://www.cwgtech.com/using-android-webview-to-display-a-webpage-on-top-of-the-unity-app-view/

And accompying youtube tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1hLo5C50wE

He makes an AndroidWebView and gets it working in Unity but the same methods can be applied for all Android stuff.

There is also Android docs here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

You can definitely create native Android plugins